# Is it possible to install both Xcode 3 and 4 side-by-side, alternate use either one or the other 

Tags: development, command-line, homebrew, xcode

I've got a handle on how to install Xcode 3 and 4 on the same machine (running OS X < 10.7), so I'm looking more how to manage this environment.

Rather: is it possible to enter some shell command to "point" to the Xcode version you would like to use for a certain task?

For example, some packages in Homebrew seem to have issues with Xcode 4 compilers (multiple `-arch` flags not supported any longer etc.). So, when I want to `brew install` something, I would like to use the old Xcode 3 gcc suite. But when doing actual Cocoa development, I  would rather like to use Xcode 4.

[RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) also does a nice job of managing work in multiple environments. I think, newer Linux distributions offer a tool called update-alternatives to achieve such a goal. Just to give you more of an idea of what I am talking about.

Similar to [running both simultaneously](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10431/is-it-possible-to-run-both-xcode-3-and-4-side-by-side-on-the-same-machine) except I'm looking to use them sequentially.

Comment: Forgive the heavy handed edit. I wanted to emphasize how detailed you crafted this to avoid any confusion with the linked question.

Comment: No prob, thanks for the effort. And thanks for the pointer to RVM, might be useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only have one version of the command-line tools installed at the same time, and I believe it says this during the installation process, so you won't really be able to switch between them.

Comment: This might be manageable with shell functions to automate changes to $PATH - Xcode 4 now drops it's command line in `/Developer/usr/bin` ([see this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/is-there-a-second-step-needed-to-activate-the-command-line-tools-in-xcode-4)) If @stamineus installs Xcode 3 smartly, they might coexist much nicer than the named applications Like Xcode and Instruments will as they are likely to fight over who opens the same UTI / file type.

Comment: OK, +1 for the info, although it being a disappointing one. If there won't turn up any positive solutions, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @bmike: It does look like I have stuff in `/Developer/usr/bin`, but I also have it in `/usr/bin` (I do also happen to have Xcode 3 installed; maybe that's why) and `/Developer/usr/bin` isn't in my `$PATH`...